# Integrate Apollo for iOS with already-existing project?

Tags: ios, graphql, apollo

Are there any guides on how to integrate the Apollo GraphQL SDK with an existing iOS project? I already have hundreds of data types and I need to pair those with the graphql counterparts, but the few tutorials I've found only demonstrate how to integrate Apollo with a brand new project.

Comment: I guess you will not find such a tutorial. I think that Apollo assumes that you will be using their generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Either use GraphQL Apollo Code generated data models in your project.
2. Transform GraphQL models into your legacy model and pass them in application.